# substring doesn't match string

Tags: vb.net

I've got the following function that when it opens a file to establish the file type doesn't return the correct value. What am I doing wrong?

The first 8 characters are in this format
%PDF-1.4

```
Function GetFileType(xFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim fileBytes As Byte()

    fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(xFile)

    Dim s As String
    s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes)

    Select Case s
        Case s.Substring(1, 3) = "PDF"
            GetFileType = False
        Case Else
            GetFileType = True
    End Select

End Function
```

It doesn't match the case statement, it's always moves to the else part which has me stumped.

Comment: Use the debugger and look at the values.

Comment: I've used the debugger, the values look correct!

Comment: `Select Case s.Substring(1, 3)`  `Case "PDF"`

Comment: VB.NET doesn't actually support this kind of Case statement syntax.  Option Strict On allows the compiler to tell you about it.  Consider a simple If-statement instead.

Comment: For file signature detection, you'd be better off doing a byte-wise comparison. Besides being more reliable (converting to UTF-8 could result in invalid characters about which you don't care), you don't have to read the whole file to determine that those 8 bytes match the signature. Open a `FileStream`, read up to 8 bytes, and compare (against the characters of the signature's *ASCII* characters as byte values).

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day. Thanks Hans!

Comment: madreflection, I'm open to improvements, can you point me to some code to get started?

Comment: @user2496011: [This answer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014518) is pretty close to what I was suggesting. It also compares just the constant part of the header, `"%PDF-"`, so you don't get false negatives on other versions (assuming you don't want to be limited to 1.4 files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to use a case statement?

In this case (see what I did there?), a simple `If` will work:

```vb
Function GetFileType(xFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim fileBytes As Byte()

    fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(xFile)

    Dim s As String
    s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes)

    if s.Substring(1, 3) = "PDF" then
            GetFileType = False
    Else
            GetFileType = True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Or just GetFileType = s.SubString(1, 3) <> "PDF".

Comment: @HansPassant, excellent catch! But I still would suggest the simple `If Then Else` since it provides a more generalized method that works for more situations than this special case.